# On Windows 10, is there a file I can modify to configure the default apps?

Tags: windows-10, default-settings, app

I know that generally I must rely on Windows prompts to manage the default apps associated to any given file extension or protocol ( https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2015/05/20/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10122-for-pcs/ ), but I am wondering if there is a file where I can do this manually?

Thanx

Comment: What is the purpose of that article from nearly 8 years ago?

Comment: @Ramhound The article announced the change that was made on Windows 10 on how the user would be able to associate the app to a given file or protocol "We know your defaults matter to you. With Windows 10, all apps – both Classic Windows apps and Universal Windows apps – will be unable to invoke a prompt to change your defaults, only Windows..... For example – if you install a new photo editor... Windows will show you a prompt...." Within the context of my question, my linking of the article may yield credibility to my statement "I know that..."

Comment: Would have help if you had quoted the relevant information from the article you were specifically interested in, the article was also talking about improvements to EdgeHTML Edge, which no longer exists.  FileExts hasn’t exactly changed significantly over the years either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default apps are [maintained in the Windows Registry](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3c32801-2c42-4dd6-84aa-5a7ce5e8016b/where-are-the-default-program-settings-stored?forum=win10itprosetup) at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\`. It's easy to view and modify the items shown in the *Open with >* context menu. In the example below, *brave.exe* and *msedge.exe* are two choices that are available in that menu.

[image: Open-With List in Registry]

However, setting a particular app as the *user choice* is *not* easily done through the Registry, because the choice is *encrypted*, as shown below. Microsoft chose to do so to prevent malicious apps from setting themselves as default. Coincidentally, it also made it more difficult for a user to select a non-Microsoft product as default, e.g., replacing *Edge* as the default browser with *Firefox* or *Brave*.

[image: User app choice in Registry]

If you want a new application as default, it can be added through the shell menu. For example, to add *pestudio* as an application that can open any (wild card, *) file when right-clicked, in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`, add the keys and values as shown below, not encrypted.

[image: Pestudio added to shell menu]

Comment: @DigitalStreaming - Might edit your question with enough details from that key.